# How can I tell a creature occupying more than one square is affected by an area spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, creature-size, area-of-effect

In our last gaming session our enemies cast a silence spell. The bard had used Alter Self to a change into an Asabi, one of the few large humanoids. Two of his squares were inside the silence spell, two outside.

I recalled a rule that at least half of a creature has to be inside an area spell to be affected, but I could not find it. I wondered, if that was a 3E rule that had been revised. The only rule I could find was this one:

> The point of origin of a spell is always a grid intersection. **When
>   determining whether a given creature is within the area of a spell**,
>   count out the distance from the point of origin in squares just as you
>   do when moving a character or when determining the range for a ranged
>   attack. The only difference is that instead of counting from the
>   center of one square to the center of the next, you count from
>   intersection to intersection. You can count diagonally across a
>   square, but remember that every second diagonal counts as 2 squares of
>   distance. **If the far edge of a square is within the spell’s area,
>   anything within that square is within the spell’s area.**

So: is a creature affected by an area spell in DnD 3.5 if a single square of its space is within the area of effect? Or, if not: how many squares of a 4 square creature does it take to affect the creature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If the far edge of a square is within the spell’s area, anything within that square is within the spell’s area.**

This means that if you have a large creature -- which occupies 4 squares -- and any one of those 4 squares are in the area of effect per the above sentence, the creature is affected.

Comment: Ok, so if I got four colossal spiders sitting right next to each other at one grid intersection I get them all with a 5-foot-radius spell like faerie fire. Impressive effect for a small spell. On the other hand - otherwise they would be totally immune to these spells.

Comment: @Giorin Yes, a 5ft radius spell actually hits a 2x2 square area and yes, if there are 4 large creatures who share the intersection that is the center of the area, you'll catch 'em all with it.  Pretty nifty, eh?

Comment: Lightning bolt also has a nifty ability that if you cast it down the center line, it hits both sides...

Comment: Anything that hits any part of a square, even the edge, affects the entire square, and the entire creature in that square, even when they are large.  (rule as written).